# How to re-size / re-arrange layout on Orientation change (Apache Cordova)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, android-layout

Any way to change the layout in html file on orientation change I have made an app looking perfect on portrait but when i switch to landscape it is messed up because buttons and other things are going down and i dont want that. I want to re-arrange the elements on landscape any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Try to clarify your question as much as you can

Comment: I think the question is clear : I am asking the way to change the layout based on orientation for android app build using apache cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you 2 ways. Now nobody will provide full code, these are hints.

1) [Media Query CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

using this you will be able to write css for different situation like what if it's get max-width 600px or more than that. By this you can fix a threshold width for example: portrait max-width:650px. Then you can write separate css for width less than 650px(portrait) & more than 650(landscape).

2)

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

function doOnOrientationChange()
{
switch(window.orientation) 
{  
  case -90:
  case 90:
    alert('landscape');
    break; 
  default:
    alert('portrait');
    break; 
}
}
```

This event will detect portrait & landscape on change. Then apply different css with elements dynamically using javascript / jquery etc.

Comment: Thanks ... I will try to use 2nd option as 1st option will not work in my case as my app will also be available on tablets.